# Expression simplification in sympy -- symbolic integration

Tags: python, computer-algebra-systems, symbolic-computation

I am trying to integrate $$p_1=\int_0^1\int_z^1\int_y^1\frac{6x^2}{(x+y)(x+y+z)}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}z$$ which arose in connection with an [earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3625137/three-way-duel-which-gun-to-choose/3625420#3625420).

When I plug it into sympy, I get back a hot mess of unevaluated double integrals.  Since I think (though I may be wrong) that the integral is elementary, I've been playing around with it.  Finally, I tried to compute the innermost integral indefinitely with

```
simplify(integrate(6*x**2/((x+y)*(x+y+z)), x))
```

which gives
$$\frac{6 \left(x z + y^{2} \log{\left (\frac{x \left(2 y^{2} + 2 y z + z^{2}\right) + 2 y^{3} + 2 y^{2} z + y z^{2}}{2 y^{2} + 2 y z + z^{2}} \right )} - \left(y + z\right)^{2} \log{\left (\frac{x \left(2 y^{2} + 2 y z + z^{2}\right) + 2 y^{3} + 3 y^{2} z + y z^{2} + z \left(y + z\right)^{2}}{2 y^{2} + 2 y z + z^{2}} \right )}\right)}{z}$$

No wonder it can't do the integration!  However, the first logarithm simplifies to $\log(x+y)$ and the second to $\log(x+y+z)$.  If I ask sympy to simplify these expressions, it has no difficulty.

So, if it were really import to compute this integral exactly, the only way I can see is to write the antiderivative as a function:

```
def f(x): 
    return 6*(x*z + y**2*log(x+y) - (y + z)**2*log(x+y+z))/z
```

evaluate $f(1)-f(y)$ in sympy, integrate the result with respect to $y$, and go through the same procedure again.

Is there a better way?

---

In answer to Eric's comment, at the end I had, among other things,
$$\int\frac{-2\log(z+1)+2\log2}z\, \mathrm{d}z$$
for which sympy gave me

```
2*log(2)*log(z) + 2*polylog(2, z*exp_polar(I*pi))
```

I take the second term to be a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) 
$$2\operatorname{Li}_2(e^{i\pi}z)=
2\operatorname{Li}_2(-z)=
2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-z)^n}{n^2}$$
but of course, the first term will blow up at $z=0$.    It seemed to me that everything else would be integrable with no difficulty.  I must have made a mistake somewhere, but it's hard to find.

I tried it again and it gave me NAN.  I made a lot of manual adjustments along the way, and I might have made a mistake, but I don't think so.

Comment: That way lead to some complex number as a result in the end for me. Have you tried it out to the end？

Comment: An inverse hyperbolic tangent $tanh^{-1}$ must have appeared somewhere for this integration. What did you do with it?

Comment: @Eric No, nothing but logarithms and polynomial until the very end.  Frankly, I think it would be easier to do this by hand.